# Function prolog in terms of memory

Tags: memory, assembly, stack

I'm trying to understand how function prolog work in assembly. My books shows the following code:

```
    push    %ebp
    movl    %ebp, %esp
```

In the definition of push it says that it decrements the value of the ESP by 4 (bytes?) and then puts the operand into the memory specified by the ESP. However won't this overwrite some data as shown in the diagram?
[image]

Also I am assuming here that each segment is 4 (bytes?) however I'm pretty sure functions can have more than 4 bytes of allocated stack space?

Following through, the second instruction moves the contents at ESP, into EBP however what need is there for that? That is already there? And when `pop` is called how does it know how much to take away from the stack? (All of what I explained assume the fact that the instructions `mov` and `push` start from where they are pointed and go up the memory when doing any operation)

Comment: In AT&T assembly your prolog code would rather look like: `pushl %ebp` `movl %esp, %ebp`. If it was a typo, then please correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack on x86 machines grows down, from higher address to lower ones.
This is reflected by the semantic of the `push` instruction:

`push ebp`

is semantically equivalent to

```
sub esp, 04h
mov DWORD [esp], ebp
```

Technically we say that the stack is *full descend*, *full* because `esp` always point to the last value pushed on and *descending* for obvious reasons.

As a matter of fact **everything above the stack pointer** have been pushed by some code an so it is initialized and implicitly allocated memory.
On the other way around, **everything below the stack** is free memory.

Thereby a `push ebp` don't overwrite anything useful, in general no *push* ever do that.

The `mov ebp, esp` doesn't take what is at *EBP* (that would have been `mov ebp, DWORD [esp]`, rather it copy the content of the *ESP* register itself into *EBP*.
*EBP* is used for two reasons:

1. It implicitly use the *SS* selector, while other register use *DS*.
2. In 16 bit pure code, only few registers could be used as bases, *(E)BP* was one specially designed for this.
   Having *(E)BP* point to the value of *ESP* comes out to be very handy for accessing the stack randomly and with fixed offsets.

Finally, the `pop` instruction is like the `push` one, its operand determines the size of operation: `push ax/eax/rax` push respectively 2, 4 and 8 bytes on the stack.
The programmer still have the burden to keep the stack balanced and if required even aligned, but that's usually not much to ask.

---

**Note**: x86 memory is byte addressable, so when an indirect register addressing is made, i.e. when we access an address specified in a register like with `mov eax, DWORD [ebx]`, that number indicates the address in terms of bytes.
Decrementing that number by *N* means reading *N* bytes lower, so subtracting 4 from *ESP* leaves four bytes between the new and old addresses in *ESP*.

Comment: When you say "esp" points to the last value pushed; Does it point at the lowest memory address? (so if you were to push 0b0001 and then read `esp[0]` would you get 1 or 0?

Comment: Also the `move` and `push` 'deal' with the <b>contents</b> of the registers and not with the memory specified by the contents of the register

Comment: @Bula *ESP* is the stack pointer, being the stack full descending, *ESP* holds the address where the last value has been pushed into. If you `push DWORD 1` followed by a `mov eax, DWORD [esp]` then *EAX* is 1. In Intel syntax *indirect* and *direct* register addressing is told by the use of `[]`.

Comment: right ok. It seems I was thinking that ESP points to the end of the very last thing that has been pushed onto the register. So if you had `push DWORD 1` followed by `move eax DWORD [esp]` my wrong understanding was that eax would be "1000....00" however from my revised understanding it will be "0000...1".  I believe I wrongly assumed it was reading memory from high to low.

Answer (score 0):

Bula

How many bytes are consumed with a register push is dependent on register sizes, which is in turn a function of the chip architecture. In your example you are using 32 bit registers so 4 bytes will be consumed with each register push.

For x86 explanation this [description](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/) may be very helpful.